# How to add multiple Pins (MapMarkers) to the Map View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mkmapview

Im trying to pin the locations on the mapview but the errors keep coming up

I tried adding all the PinItem to the annotationItems but that doesn't work

```
struct Store_locator_page: View {

    struct PinItem: Identifiable{
        let id = UUID()
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }

    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:.init(latitude: -32.5, longitude: 115.75),latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)

    let locations = [
        PinItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.5, longitude: 115.75)),
        PinItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.7, longitude: 115.9)),
        PinItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.6, longitude: 115.8)),
        PinItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.4, longitude: 115.7))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            Map(coordinateRegion : $region,
                interactionModes: [],
                showsUserLocation: true,
                userTrackingMode: nil,
                annotationItems: [PinItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.5, longitude: 115.75))]
            ) { item in
                MapMarker(coordinate: item.coordinate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't add code as images when asking questions. Copy and paste the code directly into your question, and preferable only include the code that's relevant for the problem you're facing. By improving your question, you increase your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following technique to append multiple pins to the Map view.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        "\(latitude)-\(longitude)"
    }
}

struct Place: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let color: Color
}
```

[image]

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:.init(latitude: -32.5,
                                                       longitude: 115.75),
                                               latitudinalMeters: 100_000,
                                              longitudinalMeters: 100_000)
    let annotations = [
        Place(name: "Andy's Place",
        coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.5, longitude: 115.75),
             color: .black),
        
        Place(name: "Jane's Place",
        coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.7, longitude: 115.9),
             color: .pink),
        
        Place(name: "Rick's Place",
        coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.6, longitude: 115.8),
             color: .indigo),
        
        Place(name: "Lola's Place",
        coordinate: .init(latitude: -32.4, longitude: 115.7),
             color: .orange)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {

        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) {

            MapMarker(coordinate: $0.coordinate, tint: $0.color)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```